# Inorder traversal of binary search tree

Tags: c, tree

How does the recursive function work ? In each case is traverse veing called with temp->left and temp->right or all calls of temp->left is followed by all calls of temp->right? Please do give a detailed explanation for the following code.

```
   void traverse(bst *temp)
  {   
       if(temp)
      {
          traverse(bst->left);
          printf("%d",temp->info);
          traverse(bst->right);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Draw a simple tree on paper, then using the algorithm in the code, traverse the tree on paper.

Comment: You should write out your own homework answers instead of trying to get SO contributors to do it for you:(

Comment: This *isn't* an inorder traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you edited your code .So according to that -

```
void traverse(bst *temp)  // function to traverse in a bst (parameter as root )
 {   
    if(temp)            // check temp (if not NULL then proceed)
     {
        traverse(bst->left);     // recursive call with root as left child and traverse left sub-tree till it goes to last node.
        printf("%d",temp->info); //  print value of data at current node
        traverse(bst->right);    // recursive call with root as right child and traverse right sub-tree till it goes to last node
     }
 }
```

`traverse(bst->left);` with this call it goes to last node of left sub-tree and when `if` condition becomes `false` it returns to previous call and print value at that node and then next recursive call `traverse(bst->right);` is executed and right sub-tree of that current root is traversed until `temp` becomes `NULL`.

Comment: yes thank you..had written in a swift..have edited it....could you please tell me the way it works ?

Comment: @SuchiSmith I have edited the answer .Please take a look.

Comment: how is the control even coming to the printf statement ? each time the control is getting tranferred from traverse(bst->left). all calls of traverse(bst->left) gets stored in the stack frame. when the last node is reached how is the prntf statemnt being executed..and then how is the control switching to traverse(bst->right) ?

Comment: @SuchiSmith  As  after last node `temp` becomes `NULL` it retruns to previous recursion call and value is printed  and then the `traverse(bst->right)` is executed.